# LG Optimus zone 2 adb connection problems

Tags: android, adb

I have purchased an lg optimus zone 2 to develop on and I have removed all of the drivers for the phone on my windows 7 machine. I downloaded the OEM driver from LG and disconnected my network. After installing the OEM driver I connected my device to my computer ( and I have already enabled developer mode on my device and selected USB debugging), but when I run adb devices it says that no devices are connected. Clearly it is installed on my machine because it compmgmt.msc it says that it found the LG Android MTP, and on the device itself it asks me for internet connection/ mtp/ camera or just charging mode. ( I always select the MTP mode). I for the life of me can't figure out why it won't connect (I'm trying to test an app locally on the machine), maybe I should stick to iPhone development :-(.

Comment: I will do my best to bring you to the dark side...Have you tried using another USB port?

Comment: Yes I have tried all of my ports and tried rebooting. I've tried all the different connection modes with the phone to still no avail. My sdk is at the latest level, as well as the platform tools.

Comment: What's device manager say? Edit: compmgmt is device manager (parent). It should show an ADB driver, as MTP is not ADB. I've had the best luck with charging only as android acts strange with MTP (My nexus 7 can't be used with ADB with MTP for example).

Comment: Additionally if it's rooted you could go with a wireless ADB (I use Wifi ADB). No drivers required.

Comment: I'll try charging only, but really for debugging and following along in class I wanted traditional usb connection.  Yeah device manager shows the MTP driver and not the abd driver.

Comment: Yeah device manager shows the MTP driver and not the abd driver. I guess I'm not quite sure about what you mean by the ADB driver since none of the drivers I've downloaded either OEM or google universal driver work

Comment: The odd thing I will note is that when I set my phone to debugging mode, and select usb debugging, its grayed out and I select revoke all previous authorizations (of computers). I never actually get a prompt to trust the computer I'm trying to connect the phone to by usb. That's probably the main reason I am unable to touch the phone.